# Why is not rendering the template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

This is my create view I want to call each form one at a time.
on getting to the second step organizer form after submitting the form,
it does nothing instead of rendering the next form and html

what I wanted to do is create `venue_form`, create `organizer_form` save it
and populate them to event before saving `event_form` but `event_form` template is not rendering.

What am I doing wrong.

```
def create_event(request, step=None):
venue_form = VenueForm()
organizer_form = OrganizerForm()
event_form = EventForm()
ctx = {
    'venue_form': venue_form,
    'organizer_form': organizer_form,
    'event_form': event_form,
}
if request.method == "POST":
    venue_form = VenueForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'event/organizer_form.html', ctx)
if request.method == "POST":
    organizer_form = OrganizerForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'event/event_form.html', ctx)
else:
    return render(request, 'event/venue_form.html', ctx)
```

Comment: Because if `request.method == 'POST'` it will take the first `if`. The second `if` will never "fire", since these are already triggered (and returned) by the first `if`. Note that you should redirect in case of a successful POST request.

Comment: Oh, makes sense.

Comment: How do I return the last render.

Answer (score 0):

There is a duplicated statement:

```
if request.method == "POST":
```

Therefore, the interpreter only executes the first one.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you want to have a "form wizard", which allows you to have multiple forms in different steps. I have successfully used this lib for that: https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html

It seems a bit complicated at first, but it's pretty simple once you have done it once or twice. Just follow their tutorial and you should be able to achieve that you are trying.

If you are using Django < 1.8, it is integrated. But they removed in in 1.8 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#removal-of-django-contrib-formtools).

Comment: It seems complicated that was why I decided to do it on my own and save it on session.

Comment: If you try to implement this yourself, you need to write a lot of code. That lib takes care of that and offer a lot of additional features. I would recommend, use that instead of trying your own solution, because you will run into other issues along the road.

Comment: Plus, it's a really good libary and skill to be able to build form wizards. It's worth the investment to learn it.

Comment: I will try again.

Comment: Don't worry, it took me also some time to understand it. But afterwards I can say, it's worth it.